# npm bin return me "/usr/local/bin/X: 1: /usr/local/bin/X: Syntax error: "(" unexpected" when calling it

Tags: node.js, npm

So i'm just trying to create an npm bin who create a file in the current directory.

```
// ./index.js
const program = require('commander');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

program
  .command('c <name> <content>')
  .action((name, content) => {
    fs.writeFile(path.resolve(process.cwd(), name), content, err => err ? console.error(err) : console.log('Success'));
  });

program.parse(process.argv);
```

This is not because of fs, even if i replace the `writeFile` by a console.log i still have to same error.

Here's my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "test-crayzzit",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.19.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "testcc": "./index.js"
  },
  "version": "1.0.3"
}
```

Everything's work well if i do something like `node index.js test.txt hello`

But if i install the package with npm : `sudo npm i -g test-crayzzit`

And do `testcc c test.txt hello`

It return me an error : `/usr/local/bin/testcc: 1: /usr/local/bin/testcc: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

You can try by your self with the package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-crayzzit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the shebang. The first line of index.js should read as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Moreover, the file should have `LF`line endings to be read properly on MacOS, Linux and Windows if you care about using the package on different platforms.

EDIT: I have tested your package (same error for me on Linux). Adding the shebang as described above works for me.

See also: [Appropriate hashbang for Node.js scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638520/appropriate-hashbang-for-node-js-scripts/28646724)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It also work for me, but what did you mean when you say : _the file should have `LF` line endings to be read properly_ ?

Comment: Forget about this one. With earlier versions of Node.js there were issues with executable scripts on MacOS if the file had been published on Windows. So the general advice was to convert the file to `LF` line endings before publishing it. However, since npm@5.4.0 this is no longer an issue as this version added auto-conversion. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344858/node-script-executable-not-working-on-mac-env-node-r-no-such-file-or-directo